# Flash AS3 - Second video created on stage is the same size as the first

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, size

Even though I specify different widths and heights for each.

```
vid = new Video(600, 800);
this.addChild(vid);
trace(vid.width); //600
trace(vid.height); //800

vid2 = new Video(1000, 1200);
this.addChild(vid2);
trace(vid2.width); //600
trace(vid2.height); //800
```

What is going on here? Is this a flash bug?

Comment: What happens when you instantiate vid2 first? Do the values stay the same or does vid trace out 1000, 1200?

Comment: Yes, if I switch the order, they both get sized to 1000x1200.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. The workaround is simple - you just need to manually set the width and height after you have called the constructor. I do this by creating my own Video class which inherits from the one in flash.media, like so:

```
package com.ganzogo.media {

  import flash.media.Video;

  public class Video extends flash.media.Video {

    public function Video(width:int=320, height:int=240) {

      super(width, height);
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;

    }
  }
}
```

Then just import this class and your code should work. Notice that I am setting defaults for the dimensions; this is to match the defaults in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might solve the display problem, but we have another catastrophe problem here. When you use the BitmapData to "draw" the video content we have this issue again and no matter what you try to do the image you snapshot from the video is in the size you gave the first Video component for that FlashPlayer instance was created on.

No matter what you do it won't solve it. So the workaround is as follows:

1. Give the first Video object you create the max size in pixels you can have for your videos. For example:

   ```
   var videoDisplay:Videonew Video(1280, 720);
   ```
2. To snapshot the video display you need to use the Matrix class, for example:

   ```
     var extractImage:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoDisplay.videoWidth, videoDisplay.videoHeight);
     var videoMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
     videoMatrix.scale(Number(videoDisplay.videoWidth) / 1280.0, Number(videoDisplay.videoHeight) / 720.0);
     extractImage.draw(videoDisplay, videoMatrix, null,null,null, true);
   ```

Now when you use this Bitmap as image you will get the right image you want to.
If you use larger videos resolution, increase that video size.

Comment: Please make use of your `Shift` key.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your sample code in Flash CS4 on the Mac and I didn't see this problem (I had to add `var` before the variable names). What version and platform are you using? It might be a bug.